# How to force Werror=declaration-after-statement with -std=c99 in clang

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, clang, c99

I would like to have compiler throw an error every time there is a declaration after statement because that is the coding style I want to enforce, but I also want to compile with -std=c99 since I use some of the specific c99 features.

The problem is that in c99 declarations are allowed anywhere in the code, not just at the beginning of a block.

Take a look at the following program:

```
// prog.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    int i = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile this code with **gcc** like this:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Werror=declaration-after-statement prog.c
```

it throws the following error:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:6:9: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]
    6 |         int i = 0;
      |         ^~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

This is the behavior I would like to have when compiling with **clang**, but **clang** behaves differently.

If I compile the same code with **clang** like this:

```
clang -std=c99 -Werror=declaration-after-statement prog.c
```

it throws no errors.

Only if I compile the code with **clang** like this it throws the error I want:

```
clang -std=c90 -Werror=declaration-after-statement prog.c

prog.c:6:6: error: ISO C90 forbids mixing declarations and code [-Werror,-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
        int i = 0;
            ^
1 error generated.
```

But this is not good for me because I need to use `-std=c99`.

Is it possible to force `-Werror=declaration-after-statement` along with `-std=c99` when compiling with **clang**?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: **Why** would you like to prohibit declarations after statements?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Forcing all declaration at top of scope decreases readability. Do you require compatibility with compilers from ancient times.

Comment: @lkudra All try to make their code better you try to make your code worse.:)

Comment: I'd say you've found a compiler bug. `#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wdeclaration-after-statement"` doesn't work either unless you use `-std=c90`.

Comment: Also `#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wdeclaration-after-statement"` works fine in gcc no matter C standard version, but doesn't work in clang. So that would be yet another clang bug.

Comment: This particular coding style guideline is counterproductive. Declare things right where you need them, not where an irrelevant ancient compiler could cope.

Comment: @gerhardh: If they required compatibility with an antediluvian language, they couldn't use C99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of clang it seems like not supported.

The diagnostic is defined in `clang/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticSemaKind.td`

```
def ext_mixed_decls_code : Extension<
  "ISO C90 forbids mixing declarations and code">,
  InGroup<DiagGroup<"declaration-after-statement">>;
```

And its only usage is in `clang/lib/Sema/SemaStmt.cpp`

```
StmtResult Sema::ActOnCompoundStmt(SourceLocation L, SourceLocation R,
                                   ArrayRef<Stmt *> Elts, bool isStmtExpr) {
  const unsigned NumElts = Elts.size();

  // If we're in C89 mode, check that we don't have any decls after stmts.  If
  // so, emit an extension diagnostic.
  if (!getLangOpts().C99 && !getLangOpts().CPlusPlus) {
    // Note that __extension__ can be around a decl.
    unsigned i = 0;
    // Skip over all declarations.
    for (; i != NumElts && isa<DeclStmt>(Elts[i]); ++i)
      /*empty*/;

    // We found the end of the list or a statement.  Scan for another declstmt.
    for (; i != NumElts && !isa<DeclStmt>(Elts[i]); ++i)
      /*empty*/;

    if (i != NumElts) {
      Decl *D = *cast<DeclStmt>(Elts[i])->decl_begin();
      Diag(D->getLocation(), diag::ext_mixed_decls_code); // <-- here
    }
  }
  ...
```

Note the `!getLangOpts().C99` in the `if`. The diagnose code will never execute with a standard above `c90`.

Well one thing you can surely try is build clang by yourself and delete that part of the `if` so end up with `if (!getLangOpts().CPlusPlus)`.

I tried and it worked for me.

You can configure the clang build with `cmake -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang" -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/bin/gcc" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/bin/g++" -DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=2 -DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON path/to/llvm-project/llvm`

Comment: This has changed with Clang 14, the standard check has been removed.